# Detailed view controller not showing from uilistview didSelect event

Tags: ios

didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is firing but the view controller is not.  I have tried different view controllers that I know are working.  Since the method is firing then I can only speculate that

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
```

is not reaching the navigation stack.

But I call the Calendar View Controller from a tabbarcontroller so I do not know what to do to fix this.

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

    GlobalSingleton *myAppID = [GlobalSingleton sharedSingleton];
    myAppID.globalAppID = @"627";

    UIViewController  *calendarVC;

    calendarVC = [[[CalendarViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CalendarViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];

    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[calendarVC];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    self.tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = nil;
    return YES;
}
```

CalendarViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     NSLog(@"Row %@",[events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] );

    CalendarDetailVC *detailVC = [[CalendarDetailVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"CalendarDetailVC" bundle:nil];
    detailVC.dictEvent = [events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a navigation controller in your hierarchy, so you can't so a push. You need to add a line to create the navigation controller,

```
calendarVC = [[[CalendarViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CalendarViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UINavigationController *nav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: calendarVC] autorelease];   
self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease]; 
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[nav];
```

Comment: Perfect. So instead of trying to put the nav stack in the CalendarViewController then using it to call the detail I need to use the Nav stack to call both the Parent View controller and the detail.   Thanks   -- also there is a [ missing from UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationControlle...